# How to use wordpress template is_single() in twig template

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, twig

I have this include file with following code. I assume I can used wordpress is_single() to twig template file. When I tried to accessing the detail page of a wordpress post this display the word `Nothing`.

Even though I have a post name `foo post` and I did also create a rev_slider named foo post.

```
{% if wp.is_single('foo post') %}
   {{ wp.do_shortcode('[rev_slider foo post]')|raw }}
{% else %}
   Nothing
{% endif %}
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the var `wp` is the right object?

Comment: As I observed that's what  my current wordpress theme been using while it's inside the twig file.

Comment: Try do dump the function and see what it outputs : `{{ dump(wp.is_single('foo post')) }}`, other than that you are using it right in twig

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but just be sure you have the right post title or the right post name is `wp.is_single()`

Comment: Indeed..I found out the from problem came from `{# include 'filename.twig' #}` still commented. DarkBee already given me a hint by using `{{ wp.dump() }}` which I forgot to used in twig file.